# Какова сложность моей реализации алгоритма 'Решето Эратосфена', как улучшить?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сложность

Помогите разобраться со сложностью алгоритма. Пытался реализовать 'Решето Эратосфена'.

P.S. Насколько я понимаю первый цикл несмотря на `continue` имеет сложность `sqrt(N)`, а вложенный `log(N)`, получается итоговая `sqrt(N)*log(N)`?
P.P.S.Буду признателен за пример со сложностью `log(log(N))`.

Код функции ниже:

```
function filterOut(number) {
    var tempArray = new Array(number);
    var finalArray = [];
    var limit = Math.sqrt(number);
    for(var i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
        if(tempArray[i] != undefined) continue;
        else {
            for(var j=i; j*i < number; j++) {
                tempArray[j*i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for(var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if(tempArray[i] != 0) finalArray.push(i);
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: Если у вас получится - обязательно опубликуйте в каком-нибудь научном журнале! :-D Пример: `log10(log10(1000)) == 0.4771`

Comment: Посмотрели решение?

Comment: @Nikita Smith Да посмотрел и не понял к чему Вы(да еще и жирным шрифтом выделили подробное решение).Ваше решение отлично от моего тем,что Вы в цикле постоянно увеличиваете массив...посмотрите post scriptum.

Comment: На википедии описано доказательство сложности O(N*loglogN) и это доказательство применимо к вашему алгоритму.

Answer (score 1):

Для уменьшения сложности алгоритма исключите четные числа. Смысл в практических задачах их в решето добавлять, если только для демонстрации в учебных целях.
И смысл хранить в виде массива int, разумнее в битовом массиве (существенно экономите память и ресурс движка на ее выделение). Ниже генератор использующий решето.

```
function Base(size) {
  this.arr = new Uint32Array(size);
}

Base.prototype.Add = function (num) {
  this.arr[num >> 5] |= 1 << (num & 31);
};

Base.prototype.isSet = function (num) {
  return (this.arr[num >> 5] & (1 << (num & 31))) !== 0;
};

let Max = 472882240;
let base = new Base((Max >> 5) + 1);

function init() {
  for (let i = 3; i < 21800; i += 2) {
    if (base.isSet(i)) 
      continue;
    for (let x = i + i; x <= Max; x += i) {
      base.Add(x);
    }
  }
}

class Primes {

  static *stream() {
    let num = 0;
    yield 2;

    for (let i = 3; i <= Max; i += 2)
      if (!base.isSet(i)) {
        yield i;
      }

  }

}

init();
```

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю такую реализацию алгоритма "Решето Эратосфена (Sieve of Eratosthenes)" на javascript:

UPD: исправил код с учетом обсуждения в вопросе
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614967/algorithm-sieve-of-eratosthenes-by-javascript

```js
console.time('exec');
var arr = fn(Math.pow(10, 5));

function fn(n) {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, {
    length: n + 1
  }).map(function(_, i) {
    return i > 1;
  });
  var base = 2;
  while (Math.pow(base, 2) < n) {
    var counter = 2;
    while (counter * base <= n) {
      arr[counter * base] = false;
      do {
        counter++;
      } while (!arr[base]);
    }
    do {
      base++;
    } while (!arr[base]);
  }
  return arr;
}
console.timeEnd('exec');
console.log('array length: ' + arr.length);

// show result
/*
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item) {
    console.log(index);
  }
});
*/
```

Answer (score -3):

### Подробное решение:

```js
function eratosthenes(n) {
    var array = [], upperLimit = Math.sqrt(n), output = [];

    // Создаем массив от 2 до n-1
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array.push(true);
    }

    // Удаляем простые числа начиная с 2, 3, 5 ...
    for (var i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
            for (var j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                array[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Результирующий массив
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(array[i]) {
            output.push(i);
        }
    }

    return output;
};

console.log(eratosthenes(100));
```

Вообще не знал до этого что за решето Эратосфена, но задачку решил. Наслаждайтесь!